# Is input order affecting regression model result?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have X and y to train a model.

X has input x1,x2,x3,x4.

And I use this model to predict new data new_X.

but input in new_X are x3,x2,x1,x4.

X and X_new are dataframes witm many features.

Will the order of columns affect model result?

For example:   model.predict_proba(new_X)

```
x1  x2  x3
-----------
2   2   3
0   1   4
3   4   0
5   5   5

x3  x1  x2
-----------
2   2   3
0   1   4
3   4   0
5   5   5
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** YES

---

**Long answer:**

If the variables `x1,x2,x3,x4` in `X` represent the same things as variables `x3,x2,x1,x4` in `X-new`, **then yes**.

The reason is simple. Think about the following. Let's say that `x1` is the age of some people. You train the model and then you have a `weight (w)` for this variable.

Next, if you try to predict the `X_new`, this trained `weight` will be used. But now, it is going to be applied on another variable (i.e. `x3` and not `x1`).